# Javascript passing object as function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameter-passing

I'm quite new to javascript, so maybe it's a silly error.
I created an object like the follwing:

```
function objA(){
    this.prop1;
    this.prop2;
    this.prop3;
    this.func1=function(){
        alert('func1');
    }
    this.func2=function(){
        alert('func2');
    }
}
```

I now have a function where I want to pass the object:

```
var foo=new objA;

function test(foo){....}
```

The problem is that when I call test(), I get the functions in objA (objA.func1 and objA.func2) executed.
I would like just to get the properties value of objA.
I have to use another function and an array, fill the array with the properties of objA and then pass the array:

```
var arrayA={}

function fillArray(data){
    arrayA.prop1=data.prop1;
    arrayA.prop2=data.prop2;
    arrayA.prop3=data.prop3;
}

function test(arrayA){....}
```

Is it the only way or I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Yes, your test function is wrong when it does something you don't want. Could you post it please, it seems to be essential to the question?

Comment: Agreed ... without seeing the code for `test()` it's impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: As you can see there, it works normally http://jsfiddle.net/GhNmK/1/. So your test function is in cause as said Bergi

Comment: The test function is just a jquery ajax call like this:
function test(data){
   var result;
   $.ajax({
      url:url,
      data:data,
      type:'POST',
      dataType:dType,
      async:false,
      success:function(value){result=value;}
   });
   return result;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions *are* properties of an object (they are first-class values), and thus they show up in `for (var propName in myObj)` loops like any other property. You can avoid examining them further via:

```
for (var prop in myObj){
  if (!myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue; // Skip inherited properties
  var val = myObj[prop];
  if (typeof val === 'function'))  continue; // Skip functions

  // Must be my own, non-function property
}
```

Alternatively, in modern browsers you can make specific properties (like your functions) *non-enumerable*, so they won't show up in a `for ... in` loop:

```
function objA(){
  this.prop1 = 42;
  Object.defineProperty(this,'func1',{
    value:function(){
     ...
    }
  });
}
```

*For more on this, see the docs for [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).*

Finally, if you don't need to define your functions as [*closures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) you can define them on the prototype of your object in which case the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) test will cause them to be skipped:

```
function objA(){
  this.prop1 = 42;
}
objA.prototype.func1 = function(){
  // operate on the object generically
};

var a = new objA;
"func1" in a;              // true
a.hasOwnProperty("func1"); // false
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll try the prototype definition method. I choose the closures because it seems to me more clean.